# Prove that there are infinity many numbers you can't write in the form $a^{T(a)}+b^{T(b)}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Prove that there are infinity many numbers you can't write in the form $a^{T(a)}+b^{T(b)}$
where a and b are positive integers. T(a) represents the number of divisors number a has.

Source: 3rd European mathematical cup, [senior category](http://emc.mnm.hr/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/EMC-2014-Seniors-ENG.pdf).

Comment: The [EMC](http://emc.mnm.hr) problems should be solved individually. You _can_ ask these questions here, but not without meantioning that they are part of a running competition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note $T(a)$ is odd $\iff$ $a$ is a square. (To see why, note $T(p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k})=(a_1+1)\cdots(a_k+1)$.)
So we have: $a$ is not a square $\Rightarrow$ $a^{T(a)}$ is a square.
And of course: $a$ is a square $\Rightarrow$ $a^{T(a)}$ is a square.
In any case, $a^{T(a)}$ is a square and so is $b^{T(b)}$.
This means if we can prove that there are infinitely many integers that can not be written as the sum of two squares, we are done. Indeed, we can take any number congruent to $3$ modulo $4$.

Comment: Thanks a lot ^^
Can you look up my other two problems I posted today ?

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054169/find-all-real-real-functions-that-satisfy-the-following-eqation-fx2f2y2

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054190/bisectors-of-opposite-angles-of-a-circular-quadrilateral-meet-at-the-diagonal

Comment: It's better not to post links to other questions which have not much to do with this one. As you can see, a link to those questions appears in a menu on the right of this page, under 'Linked'. Users can post a link to another question in a comment/question/answer on this page, and a link to the corresponding question will be visible in the 'Linked'-menu. However this menu is meant to show questions which are related to this question and may be interesting for people who are reading this one. So it's a bit strange to have linked questions only because it's the same person who asked them. See?

Comment: Aha, I am sry then. I am still new on this site and I am not quite familiar to all the rules. Thank you for the information.

Comment: It's fine. I'm not sure if I will answer you other questions, especially the geometry one because I don't like geometry that much :). I'll think about that functional equation if I have time...